# Complex numbers $a \ne 0$ and $b \ne 0$ such that for all positive integer $n$ the equality $a^{2017^n}+b^{2017^n}=1$ holds

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contest-math

Are there complex numbers $a \ne 0$ and $b \ne 0$ such that for all positive integer $n$ the equality $a^{2017^n}+b^{2017^n}=1$ holds?

I tried  “to guess” the numbers $a$ and $b$, but I didn’t succeed.

Comment: Hint: show that $a^6=b^6=1, a+b=1$ is a sufficient condition.